# SQL Server : new column based on other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate a new value for the new column based on other columns in T-SQL.

My data is look like this:

[image]

Each row represents one person in one day.

The `WorkHours` is calculated based on the `Portion` column:

```
Round(FF.Portion * 7.4, 3) AS WorkHours
```

I want to calculate a percentage of hours which people not have been at work in relation to the TOTAL workhours for day for each school. For example if 10 people work full hour in one school for one day, it gives 74 working hours and if one person have been sick that day it will give (7,4 % 74 * 100) which is 10% (the WorkHours is calculated based on Portion column)

Comment: what version of sql server... and can you show what the expected output would be for the test data you supplied?

Comment: Thanks I am using sql server 2012 and as I tried to explain i my question, the result shold be the outcome of 3 other columns (freeday , School and workhours). The percentage of None workdays (Seek and holiday ) out of Total workhours for each school. One exepmle : In 01-01-2017  for school AA we have 7,4 +7,4 +6  total workhours ,and 6 hours of that is registered as 'Seek'  for Peter. the result should be 6 / (7,4+7,4+6) * 100 which gives 28,846. It is a view and workhours is calculated on Portion .

Comment: Peter had 7.4 for seek on that day though, correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you state Peter had 6 hours on 1/1/2017 as "seek" but it was actually 7.4. With that in mind, we can calculate your results as follows:

```
declare @table table (Name varchar(16), Date date, School char(2), FreedayCode int, Freeday varchar(64), Portion decimal (6,4))
insert into @table
values
('Mike','20170101','AA',-1,'AtWork',1),
('Mike','20170201','AA',1,'Seek',1),
('Ali','20170101','BB',-1,'AtWork',0.94594),
('Ali','20170201','BB',-1,'AtWork',0.94594),
('Sara','20170101','CC',2,'holiday',1),
('Sara','20170201','CC',1,'Seek',1),
('Peter','20170101','AA',1,'Seek',1),
('Peter','20170201','AA',1,'Seek',1),
('Nina','20170101','AA',-1,'AtWork',0.81081),
('Nina','20170201','AA',-1,'AtWork',0.81081)

select
        Name
        ,Date
        ,School
        ,FreeDayCode
        ,Freeday,Portion
        ,NewColumn = sum(case when Freeday <> 'AtWork' then Round(Portion * 7.4,3) else 0 end) over (partition by Date, School) /  sum(Round(Portion * 7.4,3)) over (partition by Date, School)
from 
    @table
order by
    Date
    ,School
```

**RETURNS**

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Name  |    Date    | School | FreeDayCode | Freeday | Portion | NewColumn |
+-------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Mike  | 2017-01-01 | AA     |          -1 | AtWork  |  1.0000 |  0.355769 |
| Peter | 2017-01-01 | AA     |           1 | Seek    |  1.0000 |  0.355769 |
| Nina  | 2017-01-01 | AA     |          -1 | AtWork  |  0.8108 |  0.355769 |
| Ali   | 2017-01-01 | BB     |          -1 | AtWork  |  0.9459 |  0.000000 |
| Sara  | 2017-01-01 | CC     |           2 | holiday |  1.0000 |  1.000000 |
| Peter | 2017-02-01 | AA     |           1 | Seek    |  1.0000 |  0.711538 |
| Mike  | 2017-02-01 | AA     |           1 | Seek    |  1.0000 |  0.711538 |
| Nina  | 2017-02-01 | AA     |          -1 | AtWork  |  0.8108 |  0.711538 |
| Ali   | 2017-02-01 | BB     |          -1 | AtWork  |  0.9459 |  0.000000 |
| Sara  | 2017-02-01 | CC     |           1 | Seek    |  1.0000 |  1.000000 |
+-------+------------+--------+-------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scsimon. :) Great